# Trouble interpreting Friedman Test for 3-way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, friedman-test

I would like to use a Friedman Test as a non-parametric alternative to a 3-way ANOVA in RStudio. I would like to measure how 'cl_conc' (Response Variable) is affected by 'soil_type' (Fixed Effect #1 - 2 levels), 'treatment' (Fixed Effect #2 - 4 levels), with 'core' as a Random Effect and 'days' as the Repeated Measure.

I aggregated the means of my variables together for the friedman.test function:

```
cl.means <- aggregate(cl_conc ~ core + days, leach.conc2, mean)
```

I then ran the data using friedman.test:

```
cl_conc_friedman <- friedman.test(cl_conc ~ core | days, data = cl.means)

cl_conc_friedman
```

I am unsure whether I am understanding the Friedman Test results correctly. Does the way that I aggregated the data accomodate what I am trying to do? When I look at the aggregated data, it is not longer separated by soil type and treatment, rather they are combined together into 24 unique variables (see image below).

[image]

Here is my code for reproducibility:

```
  core core_id sample_id soil_type treatment sample_period days rep year
2    MS     MS1     MS1-1      Silt     Solid             1    4   1    1
3    MS     MS1     MS1-2      Silt     Solid             2   11   1    1
4    MS     MS1     MS1-3      Silt     Solid             3   18   1    1
6    ML     ML1     ML1-1      Silt    Liquid             1    4   1    1
7    ML     ML1     ML1-2      Silt    Liquid             2   11   1    1
8    ML     ML1     ML1-3      Silt    Liquid             3   18   1    1
10   MK     MK1     MK1-1      Silt       KCl             1    4   1    1
11   MK     MK1     MK1-2      Silt       KCl             2   11   1    1
12   MK     MK1     MK1-3      Silt       KCl             3   18   1    1
14   MC     MC1     MC1-1      Silt   Control             1    4   1    1
15   MC     MC1     MC1-2      Silt   Control             2   11   1    1
16   MC     MC1     MC1-3      Silt   Control             3   18   1    1
18   FS     FS1     FS1-1     Clay      Solid             1    4   1    1
19   FS     FS1     FS1-2     Clay      Solid             2   11   1    1
20   FS     FS1     FS1-3     Clay      Solid             3   18   1    1
22   FL     FL1     FL1-1     Clay     Liquid             1    4   1    1
23   FL     FL1     FL1-2     Clay     Liquid             2   11   1    1
24   FL     FL1     FL1-3     Clay     Liquid             3   18   1    1
26   FK     FK1     FK1-1     Clay        KCl             1    4   1    1
27   FK     FK1     FK1-2     Clay        KCl             2   11   1    1
28   FK     FK1     FK1-3     Clay        KCl             3   18   1    1
30   FC     FC1     FC1-1     Clay    Control             1    4   1    1
31   FC     FC1     FC1-2     Clay    Control             2   11   1    1
32   FC     FC1     FC1-3     Clay    Control             3   18   1    1
34   MS     MS2     MS2-1      Silt     Solid             1    4   2    1
35   MS     MS2     MS2-2      Silt     Solid             2   11   2    1
36   MS     MS2     MS2-3      Silt     Solid             3   18   2    1
38   ML     ML2     ML2-1      Silt    Liquid             1    4   2    1
39   ML     ML2     ML2-2      Silt    Liquid             2   11   2    1
40   ML     ML2     ML2-3      Silt    Liquid             3   18   2    1
42   MK     MK2     MK2-1      Silt       KCl             1    4   2    1
43   MK     MK2     MK2-2      Silt       KCl             2   11   2    1
44   MK     MK2     MK2-3      Silt       KCl             3   18   2    1
46   MC     MC2     MC2-1      Silt   Control             1    4   2    1
47   MC     MC2     MC2-2      Silt   Control             2   11   2    1
48   MC     MC2     MC2-3      Silt   Control             3   18   2    1
50   FS     FS2     FS2-1     Clay      Solid             1    4   2    1
51   FS     FS2     FS2-2     Clay      Solid             2   11   2    1
52   FS     FS2     FS2-3     Clay      Solid             3   18   2    1
54   FL     FL2     FL2-1     Clay     Liquid             1    4   2    1
55   FL     FL2     FL2-2     Clay     Liquid             2   11   2    1
56   FL     FL2     FL2-3     Clay     Liquid             3   18   2    1
58   FK     FK2     FK2-1     Clay        KCl             1    4   2    1
59   FK     FK2     FK2-2     Clay        KCl             2   11   2    1
60   FK     FK2     FK2-3     Clay        KCl             3   18   2    1
62   FC     FC2     FC2-1     Clay    Control             1    4   2    1
63   FC     FC2     FC2-2     Clay    Control             2   11   2    1
64   FC     FC2     FC2-3     Clay    Control             3   18   2    1
66   MS     MS3     MS3-1      Silt     Solid             1    4   3    1
67   MS     MS3     MS3-2      Silt     Solid             2   11   3    1
68   MS     MS3     MS3-3      Silt     Solid             3   18   3    1
70   ML     ML3     ML3-1      Silt    Liquid             1    4   3    1
71   ML     ML3     ML3-2      Silt    Liquid             2   11   3    1
72   ML     ML3     ML3-3      Silt    Liquid             3   18   3    1
74   MK     MK3     MK3-1      Silt       KCl             1    4   3    1
75   MK     MK3     MK3-2      Silt       KCl             2   11   3    1
76   MK     MK3     MK3-3      Silt       KCl             3   18   3    1
78   MC     MC3     MC3-1      Silt   Control             1    4   3    1
79   MC     MC3     MC3-2      Silt   Control             2   11   3    1
80   MC     MC3     MC3-3      Silt   Control             3   18   3    1
82   FS     FS3     FS3-1     Clay      Solid             1    4   3    1
83   FS     FS3     FS3-2     Clay      Solid             2   11   3    1
84   FS     FS3     FS3-3     Clay      Solid             3   18   3    1
86   FL     FL3     FL3-1     Clay     Liquid             1    4   3    1
87   FL     FL3     FL3-2     Clay     Liquid             2   11   3    1
88   FL     FL3     FL3-3     Clay     Liquid             3   18   3    1
90   FK     FK3     FK3-1     Clay        KCl             1    4   3    1
91   FK     FK3     FK3-2     Clay        KCl             2   11   3    1
92   FK     FK3     FK3-3     Clay        KCl             3   18   3    1
94   FC     FC3     FC3-1     Clay    Control             1    4   3    1
95   FC     FC3     FC3-2     Clay    Control             2   11   3    1
96   FC     FC3     FC3-3     Clay    Control             3   18   3    1
   vol_leached cl_conc
2         3.25   18.10
3         3.00   18.10
4         3.50   17.40
6         3.50   77.10
7         3.25   81.40
8         3.25   66.80
10        3.00   19.40
11        3.00   22.30
12        3.25   36.90
14        3.00    1.90
15        3.00    1.20
16        3.25    0.60
18        3.25   27.80
19        3.00   28.30
20        3.00   28.30
22        3.50  107.80
23        3.00  150.30
24        3.50   94.60
26        3.25   84.80
27        3.00   53.40
28        3.00   51.90
30        3.50    9.10
31        2.50    4.25
32        3.25    1.90
34        3.25   19.80
35        3.50   20.70
36        3.50   20.50
38        3.25  102.00
39        3.50   56.70
40        3.50   47.40
42        3.25   33.40
43        3.50   15.30
44        3.25   19.90
46        3.25    2.00
47        3.25    1.20
48        3.25    0.80
50        3.00   37.10
51        3.50   39.80
52        3.00   34.80
54        3.25   81.90
55        2.75   67.50
56        3.00   56.00
58        2.75   41.10
59        2.75   38.30
60        3.00   30.90
62        3.00   12.40
63        3.00    6.00
64        3.25    3.10
66        3.25   27.80
67        3.25   27.80
68        3.00   24.90
70        3.00   79.70
71        3.50   65.50
72        3.00   55.20
74        3.00   13.50
75        3.25   20.40
76        2.50   24.70
78        3.00    1.60
79        3.00    1.20
80        3.00    0.70
82        3.00   42.70
83        3.25   40.50
84        3.25   30.10
86        3.25  121.20
87        3.25   73.60
88        3.00   38.00
90        3.25   53.00
91        3.25   38.50
92        3.00   22.30
94        3.25    4.70
95        3.25    1.90
96        2.75    0.85
```